# 4 wires in single-pole switch

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, smart-switch

[image]I am trying to put a smart switch in place of a regular one and when I opened the box I see 4 wires instead of 3 and looks like one of the black wire actually feeds the remaining devices on the circuit. Whenever I am connecting the load and live with my smart which connection it is tripping the circuit breaker.
Any suggestion how handle this?

Comment: Can you take some pictures of the box, the way it was originally wired and of your switch?

Comment: If you’re having trouble posting photos, go back to the computer you used to post this, do not clear cookies, and Register your account and tie it to an email/password, Facebook or Google ID.   That will let you log on from a different device, and you can [edit] your post from there to add pix.

Comment: When you're done [edit]ing in your pics, take the [tour] and browse the [help] while you're waiting for an answer. That will give you a better idea of how this Q&A forum differs from most discussion boards and an idea of what to expect and what _not_ to expect.

Comment: I got the light to work now but the next socket in the circuit is not getting power as I left one black wire not connected..

Comment: Any idea how to solve this issue now

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of your box please?

Answer (score 2):

If you count the numbers of lights, fans and sockets in your home, and then count the number of circuit breakers assigned to those things, you’ll notice you have a lot more outlets than circuit breakers.

That’s because each circuit powers more than one outlet/lamp/etc.

How does that work?  Hot, neutral and ground go to an outlet point like a light switch.  And then, another hot, neutral and ground goes onward from there to another outlet.  That’s normal.  *You walked right into the middle of that*.

You were expecting to see 1 always-hot, 1 switched-hot and 1 ground going to your switch.  What you actually found was a **supply** always-hot; an *onward* always-hot; and a switched-hot.  And a ground.

The supply and onward always-hot wires should have been kept together.

I gather that since the light works, your loose, unaccounted for wire is the *onward* always-hot.  Where do we attach that?  With the *supply* always-hot.

If you have no idea which that is, it won’t hurt anything if you accidentally attached it to *switched-hot* - just at that point it will be switched.  Don’t leave it that way, the smart switch may not be strong enough to switch whatever it goes to.

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation.. got it done..